# Troubleshoot slow download speed on aws ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, scp

I have 8 instances on ap-northeast-1a. Types are t3a.medium, t2.small and c5d.large. I also have a t2.small in the ap-northeast-1d availibility zone.

Any internet connection reaching those instances is really slow.
For example, if I try to `scp` a file, I get download speeds of around 20KB/s, then it slowly goes down to about 10kb/s. My local machine is in France.

```
scp my_user@production_server:/home/my_user/big_file .
big_file                                              192KB  12.7KB/s   02:19 ETA
```

The ssh connection is really unresponsive too. For example, the output of `htop` takes a few seconds to display.

Some of the 8 instances have elastic ip, some don't. One is in a different availability zone. For all of them, I get the slow download speed.
One interesting fact is that upload is fast. I get speeds between 1 and 2 MB/s.

```
scp big_file my_user@production_server:/home/my_user
big_file                                         49% 3360KB   1.2MB/s   00:02 ETA
```

I also tried changing local internet connection to a 4g hotspot, and the behavior is the same.
I'm thinking the issue is related to network activity going out of the datacenter.

I am not a network expert, how can I troubleshoot this further?

---

**Edit**

I tried running this:
`traceroute <my-server-ip>`

It gives the following output:

```
[first 13 lines look normal]
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * 52.95.31.31 (52.95.31.31)  248.392 ms
    52.95.31.59 (52.95.31.59)  247.997 ms
18  52.95.31.165 (52.95.31.165)  249.730 ms  262.213 ms
    52.95.31.179 (52.95.31.179)  248.495 ms
19  * 52.95.31.208 (52.95.31.208)  246.955 ms *
20  52.95.31.130 (52.95.31.130)  249.471 ms  248.195 ms  250.721 ms
21  52.95.30.216 (52.95.30.216)  249.071 ms
    52.95.30.220 (52.95.30.220)  247.704 ms  247.702 ms
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
31  * * *
32  * * *
33  * * *
34  * * *
35  * * *
36  * * *
37  * * *
38  * * *
39  * * *
40  * * *
41  * * *
42  * * *
43  * * *
44  * * *
45  * * *
46  * * *
47  * * *
48  * * *
49  * * *
50  * * *
51  * * *
52  * * *
53  * * *
54  * * *
55  * * *
56  * * *
57  * * *
58  * * *
59  * * *
60  * * *
61  * * *
62  * * *
63  * * *
64  * * *
```

I didn't truncate the end or kill it while running, it ends like this.

Comment: One answer would be to try `ping` or `traceroute` as it will show the times needed to reach the next hop.

Comment: @MarkoE Thanks for the suggestion, I updated my question. Ping says: `Request timeout for icmp_seq 0, Request timeout for icmp_seq 1...`

Comment: Reponse times do not seem that bad, but comparing to the ones I see for an instance in us-east-1, they are almost double. It might be that it's because of the physical distance. Did it work better before and started working like this or you had same issue right from the start?

Comment: @MarkoE At the start, it worked great, and then the issue started happening. Another interesting thing is that the issue seems to go away in the evening (18:00 paris time) where I get download speeds in the 300BK instead of 10KB, then in the next evening, the issue comes up again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only network bandwidth limitation in AWS is related to the Instance Type of the EC2 instance.

The general rule is that **smaller instances have less bandwidth**. This is because the network capacity assigned to the Host computer is split between the instances running on that Host. If a Host is running many small instances, each are assigned a smaller amount of bandwidth.

This can be seen when launching an EC2 instance. The **Network Performance** is shown as:

- `t3a.medium`: Up to 5 Gigabit
- `t2.small`: Low to Moderate
- `c5d.large`: Up to 10 Gigabit

Therefore, please note that results can vary based on Instance Type.

However, the real problems are likely to be due to your remote location, **accessing a Tokyo server from France**. This traffic goes across the Internet, with many hops and little control.

You could attempt to use the [AWS Global Accelerator](https://aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/) that diverts traffic to use the global Amazon network. That would remove a lot of the network variability.

Comment: I would suggest to leverage AWS S3 buckets to store files instead of EC2. This way it will provide consistent performance and if needed it can be augmented with AWS Cloudfront to improve the performance.   S3 solution will be cheaper and reliable due to its AZ capabilities. If you can enable multi-region replication, it will be DR ready as well. With IAM policies, fine graned security can be provided. The overall solution becomes full proof.

Comment: Ooh, that's a good idea! Instead of copying to EC2, copy to S3 (maybe with `aws s3 sync`). Then, it is very fast to transfer data between S3 and EC2.

Comment: @RobinVarghese Thanks for suggesting S3. The way I use this server is to do queries that are then displayed in a sql client, or the data is displayed as charts. With these download speeds, just fetching the data can take minutes if the results is 1000+ rows. I am using `scp` just to investigate the download speed.

Comment: @RobinVarghese I guess I could setup db replication or a job to copy the data. But setting this up just to work around slow connections seems a bit overkill.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Adding the AWS Global Accelerator fixes my slow download issue. I get 1.2 to 2MB/s download and upload when using it. So I guess the issue was somewhere in the link between my router and the aws cloud, and I think the AWS Accelerator infrastructure bypasses that.